Why is it undefined behavior to call operator* on an empty std::optional if I don't access the returned value right away?
Why is it undefined behavior to call operator* on an empty std::optional if I don't access the returned value before emplacing an object?
For example, why is the following code UB?
std::optional<int> opt_val;
auto p_val = &(*opt_val);
opt_val.emplace(0);
    
// do something with p_val

EDIT: Original question asked if it was UB, now asking why it is UB.

The link isn't pasting properly, but yes it is, and all you have to do is look up the operator on cppreference.

It's essentially the same as dereferencing an invalid pointer. That actually tries to get the value immediately. That you don't "use" the value until later is irrelevant to accessing an invalid pointer (or std::optional).

Just to know: in gcc, in STL debug mode, you get crash just by calling *std::optional<int>{}; - just compile with -D_GLIBCXX_DEBUG

Dupe: Is use of empty std::optional UB or not?

reopened, because "EDIT: Original question asked if it was UB, now asking why is it UB."

@user12002570 the fact that answers overlap does not necessarily mean it is a dupe. The question itself is different. And the OP specifically showed that they were familiar with the post you refer to.

@user12002570 I think the different essence of the questions does matter. People searching SO in the future might be interested in both.

@user12002570 you would have a better stand if you backed your claim with a decisive meta post.

Because the standard says so. Not explicitly, but 22.5.3.6#1 says about operator*:

Preconditions: *this contains a value.

The standard does not define what happens when you call the function while the precondition is not met. It is undefined.
Actually that could make the answer already. The standard does not try to define all and everything. Instead it specifies what a method does when it is used for what it is supposed to be used for. Calling std::optional::operator* without using the result has no use. The method could even be marked as [[nodiscard]] to make it an error when the value returned is ignored. What the standard does not define is undefined.

std::optional does not use dynamic allocations. It models an object, not a pointer. Nevertheless calling operator* on a optional that does not contain an object is similar to dereferencing a null pointer.
I suppose it would be possible to write an implementation that has no issues with calling operator* on an empty optional. Though, the standard says that it is undefined, hence an implementation does not have to deal with it. That gives more freedom to implementations, and potentially grants more opportunities to the optimizer.

Defining feature of an expression IS its result, which is described by its value type and value category. It is
a requirement of language that any expression should have valid result (including void), regardless it was used or not.
*opt_val is an expression must be an lvalue of type int while opt_val is some glvalue of std::optional<int> (obviously). The former must appear from somewhere, which is not possible in case of empty optional (it's really empty, there was no object created).
This is whole point of optional<T>, it allows to have a transparent vehicle to refer to an instance of T and to the act of allocating a storage for an instance of T when required. In other words, you may consider it a type-safe wrapper around void*, except instead of nullptr it may or may not use a different null-object. It's not defined how std::optional is implemented, so effect of calling its operator* is also not defined.

*opt_val is lvalue.

Those operators have ref-qualifiers, and opt_val is lvalue.

@WeijunZhou I mean , it's not mistake to call lvalue a glvaue becuase  lvalue is a glvalue. It isn't xvalue. Ok, it's weird. Thta's machine typo. Autocorrect doesn't allow to input lvalue

Yes, but you originally wrote "rvalue". Now it looks fine.

@WeijunZhou was absolutely sure I wrote lvlaue. appears it wants to correct that. re-editing   tricks it.

Most C++ standard library implementations have optional assertions that you can enable. If you enable those, operator* will trigger an assertion when called on an empty optional.
If you change the standard to remove this UB, having this assertion becomes illegal.
